# How to check if user is in group with 'or something else' support in django template?

Tags: django, tags, django-templates

For now I used [ifuseringroup](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2566/) tag but now I need to add exception for users with specific permission so I need something like this (pseudocode)

`{% ifuseringroup 'masters' or perms.app_label.can_see_this %}`

Anyone knows a group checking tag that will accept `or` and then standard django `if` tag expression?
Or can help me using other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with [this template filter](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/847/):

```
{% if user|in_group:'masters' or perms.app_label.can_see_this %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to check for permissions in templates, the following code would suffice:

```
{% if perms.app_label.can_do_something %}
<form here>
{% endif %}
```

Where model refers to the model that the user need permissions to see the form for.

Refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#permissions for more examples.

```
The currently logged-in user's permissions are stored in the template variable {{ perms }}
```

Comment: I know that . Im looking for the way to check if user is in group or <any else template if statement returns true> like: if user is in group biggroup or his name is marta. Or: if user is in group smallgroup or perms.appllabel.canseethis. if you got the idea how to better rephrase the question fell free to suggest that.

Comment: I'm already usig it but it's not supporting `or` statement. Or maybe I'm wrong - how would you use it to check if user is in group "superg" OR his first_name is "marta"?